Need Jolt spec to convert the input json with dynamic field to output json
I need jolt spec for the below input json with dynamic date field and array of items. That jolt spec should convert this input json to below output json.
Input Json:
{
  "market": {
    "2024-04-13": [
      {
        "code": "ABC",
        "name": "Name1",
        "date": "2024-04-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 100,
        "sold": 1
      }
    ],
    "2024-04-14": [
      {
        "code": "DEF",
        "name": "Name2",
        "date": "2024-04-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 233.32,
        "sold": 3
      },
      {
        "code": "EFG",
        "name": "DISCOUNT",
        "date": "2024-04-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 300.05,
        "sold": 1
      },
      {
        "code": "MNO",
        "name": "GROUP",
        "date": "2024-04-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 45.33,
        "sold": 3
      }
    ],
    "2024-04-15": [
      {
        "code": "POR",
        "name": "TEST",
        "date": "2024-04-15T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 100,
        "sold": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}

Output json
{
  "market": {
    "DATE": [
      {
        "code": "ABC",
        "name": "Name1",
        "date": "2024-04-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 100,
        "sold": 1
      },
      {
        "code": "DEF",
        "name": "Name2",
        "date": "2024-04-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 233.32,
        "sold": 3
      },
      {
        "code": "EFG",
        "name": "DISCOUNT",
        "date": "2024-04-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 300.05,
        "sold": 1
      },
      {
        "code": "MNO",
        "name": "GROUP",
        "date": "2024-04-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 45.33,
        "sold": 3
      },
      {
        "code": "POR",
        "name": "TEST",
        "date": "2024-04-15T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rev": 100,
        "sold": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}

The below Jolt spec I tried but it is not giving me exact output. It is grouping first few items, but I need them separately  similar like the output json.
Jolt spec
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "market": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "code": "market[&1].code",
            "name": "market[&1].name",
            "date": "market[&1].date",
            "rev": "market[&1].rev",
            "sold": "market[&1].sold"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


You should separate by those dates combined with the sub-index values(0,1,2) in order to be able to distincuish all sub-objects such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { //lhe layer for the "market"
        "*": { //the layer for the arrays
          "*": { //the layer for the indexes of the arrays
            "*": "&3.&2_&1.&" // &3 : going 3 levels up to bring the literal "market"
                              // &2 : the date values
                              // &1 : the indexes of the arrays
                              // &  : the leaf node which represents the replication the respective value 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //arrange the key names of the outermost objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.DATE[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

Edit : the following option(which @samersaleh [thanks to him] proposed) would be more straightforward :
[
  { 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.DATE[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Thanks for your support @Barbaros Özhan. But I need to mention each field (like code, name, date,rev,sold etc) in jolt spec (like "code": "market[&1].code",
"name": "market[&1].name")   so that in any extra fields comes in the input json apart from what is defined in the jolt spec then those extra field should be ignored and should not be present in output json. but if we provide * it will put all the fields in the output json. Please let me know if anything.   Thanks!

Sure thing @Optimizer. In such case you write one by one as you did or "code|name|date|rev|sold": "&3.&2_&1.&" or keeping to use "*":"&"  key-value pair model as I already did, and add an extra "remove" spec in order to get rid of all unwanted attributes.

@Optimizer realised that I missed the DATE which's added right now, take care.

@Barbaros Özhan, Assuming no fields to be specified which I dont see a way to do it without second jolt, but if that was not the case then one jolt spec should be sufficient unless Im missing something: [
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"": {
"": {
"*": "market.DATE[]"
}
}
}
}
]

You're right @samersaleh , your suggestion is better

Barbaros Özhan and @samersaleh Thank you for your support. It worked. !!
